# Codeigniter ajax send data to controller using ajax code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#select-dept").change(function () {
            var id = $("#select-dept").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?=base_url()?>.index.php/sms/get_dept_employee",
                //url: baseurl + 'sms/get_dept_employee',
                data: "id",
                dataType = "json",
                cache: "false",
                success: function (emp_list) {
                    $("#dept-emp").html(emp_list);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am unable to send view data to controller function
In view their is select box with departmenr values from mysql database

```
<select class="select-dept" id="select-dept" name="select-dept">
    <option>Select Department</option>
    <?foreach ($departments as $dt):?>
        <option value="<?=$dt['id']?>">
            <?=$dt[ 'name']?>
        </option>
    <?endforeach;?>
</select>
```

i need to get refresh when user select department and that need to call controller function
**get_dept_employee**
And need to display datagrid of employee list

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to send data option as object

try this

```
 .....
 url: "<?=base_url()?>.index.php/sms/get_dept_employee",
 data: {"id":id},
 dataType:"json",
 ....
```

and get the posted value as `id` in your controller..

```
$id=$this->input->post('id');
....
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var id = $("#select-dept").val();     

 data:"id", //Here you are sending string as id
```

should be

```
     data:id, //No double quotes surrounded
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data: {'id':$(this).val()},
```

Answer (score 0):

i saw few errors

use `data: {'id':id},` instead of `data: "id",`

use `dataType:"json",` instead of `dataType="json",`

use `cache:false` instead of `cache: "false",`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var base_url = "<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>";

        $("#select-dept").change(function () {

            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url+"index.php/sms/get_dept_employee";
                data: {'id':id},
                dataType:"json",
                cache: false
                success: function (emp_list) {
                    $("#dept-emp").html(emp_list);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```